# "Visual Studio code" cursor moves to end of line automatically when taking a small pause while editing some text inside my file

Tags: visual-studio-code

Inside **Visual Studio code editor**(version 1.15.0) the cursor moves to end of line when taking a small pause while editing some text inside my file.Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by disabling all extension from visual studio code editor.Please see the a
[image]ttached image on how to Disable all extension

**After disabling all extension the cursor issue resolved and then i installed/enabled the required extensions only**

Answer (score 11):

Recently, I had the same kind of issue and the extension caused to the problem was  [EditorConfig](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig). So what I simply did is open the file:

> .editorconfig

which available in the same working directory, then I change:

```
insert_final_newline = true
```

to

```
insert_final_newline = false
```

Problem solved! :)

Answer (score 4):

This problem is due to document formatting extension installed on VS CODE. Every time you add new lines to the file and take a pause, file is formatted which will take the cursor to end of file.

Here is the simple solution of your problem:

Go to `File`, then toggle `Auto Save` option. This will also prevent auto formatting of document. Formatting will be done on manually saving the document.

If your document is not being formatted on saving the document try this:

1. Click `File > Preference > Settings`
2. Type `editor.format` in `Search Settings` input field
3. Change `editor.formatOnSave` to `true` or add the following line to settings file `"editor.formatOnSave": true`

Comment: it would be useful to have my stuff formatted with prettier on autosave, but not touch the line I'm working with right now. Do you think it's achievable?

Answer (score 4):

You can quickly go back to the previous edit location ( before save ) with:

On Mac:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> .. navigate back

On Windows:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> .. navigate back

On Ubuntu Linux:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> .. navigate back

Not exactly a solution. But, a quick dirty work-around

Answer (score 1):

I faced an issue and disabled the extension "JS, CSS, HTML Formatter". Now the issue is gone

Uninstall this --->

JS-CSS-HTML Formatter
lonefy.vscode-js-css-html-formatter
lonefy

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
In my case auto save delay time is very less that's why cursor goes end of the page after small delay.
Go to `setting` -> `commonly used` ->increase time of Auto save delay.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same issue for a few days. Previously, I was using the Prettier extension, and it worked fine with the auto save -> 'afterDelay'in settings. However, now it moves the cursor to the end of the line. So, I tried changing the 'auto save' setting to 'onFocusChange,' and it is working fine. I believe the version of VS Code may have a different impact on this Prettier extension.[image]

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Auto SaveDelay</kbd>

There you can specify the interval of inactivity in milliseconds:

[image: screenshot]

And also you can turn off autosave (by putting it in the "off" position):

[image: Screenshot]